# How to dynamically choose scheduling type?

Tags: c, openmp, schedule, pragma

I need to compare execution time of a loop with different scheduling type and threads number with openMP.

I can set threads number dynamically by passing an `int` variable directly in the pragma macro:

```
int threads_number = 4;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads_number)
```

But I'm trying to do the same for `schedule`, I need  to compare `static`, `dynamic` and `guided` types. But it appears I cannot use an int as enum nor a `char*` as name for this one.

Is there any way to choose it dynamically, or do I have to write the loop 3 times and choose which one to call with an `if`, which seems kind of dirty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the scheduling kind when the applied schedule is `runtime`.

> When schedule(runtime) is specified, the decision regarding scheduling is deferred until runtime. The schedule kind and size of the chunks can be chosen at run time by setting the environment variable OMP_SCHEDULE. If this environment variable is not set, the resulting schedule is implementation-defined. When schedule(runtime) is specified, chunk_size must not be specified. - *[OpenMP-4.5 Specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf)*

This is done with the function `void omp_set_schedule(omp_sched_t kind, int chunk_size);`

The scheduling kinds that are available are defined in `omp.h` as this enum below

```
typedef enum omp_sched_t {
    omp_sched_static = 1,
    omp_sched_dynamic = 2,
    omp_sched_guided = 3,
    omp_sched_auto = 4
} omp_sched_t;
```

Comment: Note that using schedule(runtime) and then omp_sched_static can easily produce worse results for the static schedule than you would get if the compiler knew that the schedule was static at compile time. That is because if the compiler knows that the schedule is static, it can generate better code that does not have any calls into the runtime for scheduling  inside the loop. Whereas if the schedule might be dynamic it has to use a more expensive code-generation pattern that makes a scheduling call for each "blocksize" set of iterations.